# How to use input number as Dot or Comma as decimal separator

Tags: html, angular, ionic-framework

transaction.ts

```
 numberMask = createNumberMask({ prefix: '€  ' , thousandsSeparatorSymbol: '', allowDecimal: true, decimalSymbol: ',' });
```

transaction.html

```
<ion-item lines="none">
        <input currencyMask formControlName="amount" [textMask]="{mask:numberMask}" type ="text" placeholder="€  " />
</ion-item>
```

decimalSymbol is only allowed one symbol either dot or comma.

Is there any option which allowed both symbol in input text box?

Current Issue -  I can input comma only as decimal but I would like to use both alternatively.

I would like to use both alternatively:
e.g input --> 3.22 or 3,22 as decimal separator in input

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXU7j.png)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you have to decide which separator to use and replace the other with `rgx` and `replace ()`

Comment: Europeans use comma and not the dot as separator in numbers.
While using computers, we frequently use the dot for 2 reasons:
- a lot of software don't support commas
- the numpad have a dot and not a comma in european keyboards

Comment: Yes I know. The user can type what he wants, but the page should display the correct value - with `rgx` and `replace()` you can do that. Maybe someone else knows another way, unfortunately I don't know any other solution.